# Explaining why $\sqrt {x^2+a} = x\sqrt{1+ \frac{a}{x^2}}$ For $x>0$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

I understand the technical operation of extracting $x^2$ out of the root, but is there a way proving it?

$$\sqrt {x^2+a} = x\sqrt{1+ \frac{a}{x^2}}$$

Comment: What is the difference for you between the "technical operation" and a proof?

Comment: Square the right-hand side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sqrt{x^2+a}=\sqrt{x^2\left(1+\frac{a}{x^2}\right)}=\underbrace{\sqrt{x^2}}_{=|x|}\cdot \sqrt{1+\frac{a}{x^2}}\underset{(1)}{=}x\sqrt{1+\frac{a}{x^2}}$$

*justification:*

$(1):$ Because $x>0$.

Answer (score 3):

Note that the right-hand side is positive. Square it and simplify.

Comment: The only answer that 1) is correct and 2) differs from taking $x^2$ out of the radical. +1

Comment: @FPE, What's problematic with idm's proof?

Comment: @Elimination: it is fine, I got misleaded by your question. I understood it as if you wanted a proof that does not require to "extract $x^2$ from the square root".

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that $x>0$ we have that
\begin{align}
\sqrt{x^2+a} &=\\
\sqrt{x^2\left(1+\frac{a}{x^2}\right)} &=\\
\sqrt{x^2}\sqrt{1+\frac{a}{x^2}} &=\\
|x| \sqrt{1+\frac{a}{x^2}}&=\\
x\sqrt{1+\frac{a}{x^2}}.
\end{align}
In the first equality we must require that $x\neq 0$, since otherwise the division by $x^2$ is not defined. For the next equality we have used that $\sqrt{m\cdot n} = \sqrt{m}\sqrt{n}$, which holds whenever $m,n\geq 0$. For the last equality we have, in the general case, that $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$. But since we assumed that $x>0$ we have that $|x|=x$.

Comment: "I understand the technical operation of extracting $x^2$ out of the root". I don't understand what the OP is asking for, yet I'm pretty sure he wants something else!

Comment: How I interpreted it (which might very well be wrong) is that he/she understood that $x^2$ would become $x$ when taken out of the square-root, but not the exact computation. I would consider this an acceptable proof, otherwise perhaps the question needs some clarification.

Comment: Oh, so "proving it" would mean proving that this particular step is indeed correct, that makes sense! So it'd be worth reminding that $\sqrt{ab}=\sqrt a\sqrt b$ when both $a,b>0$.

Comment: I clarified a bit on the steps :)